How to launch my app before androidtv launcher?
I have an Android application that I want to launch at startup (launcher) similar to Projectivity Launcher. I managed to configure it to launch at startup, but it starts about 10 seconds after the Android interface is launched. In fact, I don’t want to see the Android interface at startup, just my app like with Projectivity.
Thanks in advance for further responses.
I’ve manage to call my package when ever the android package was called com.google.android.tv launcher
Here is my boot receiver my function is the "setdefaultlauncher" which I call in the "onReceive" part:


package com.ansetech.hospitv.receiver;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ansetech.hospitv.activity.HomeActivity;
import com.ansetech.hospitv.service.DownloadService;
import com.ansetech.hospitv.service.NotificationService;
import com.ansetech.hospitv.service.YourBootService;
import com.ansetech.hospitvlib.util.DUtils;

/**
 * Starts download service on bootup
 */
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String LOG_CAT = "BootReceiver";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Set your app as the default launcher
        //if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            // Your code to handle boot completion goes here
            // For example, you can start a service or launch an activity
            setDefaultLauncher(context);

        //}

        // Démarrage des services.
        try {
            DUtils.caveman("BootReceive startForegroundService NotificationService....");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
            } else {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("BootReceiver", "Starting service FAILED -> NotificationService", e);
        }

        try {
            DUtils.caveman("BootReceive startForegroundService DownloadService....");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, DownloadService.class));
            } else {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, DownloadService.class));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("BootReceiver", "Starting service FAILED -> DownloadService", e);
        }

        // Start YourBootService
        try {
            DUtils.caveman("BootReceive startForegroundService YourBootService....");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, YourBootService.class));
            } else {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, YourBootService.class));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("BootReceiver", "Starting service FAILED -> YourBootService", e);
        }

        // Start HomeActivity
        try {
            DUtils.caveman("BootReceive start HomeActivity....");
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
            startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(startIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("BootReceiver", "Starting HomeActivity FAILED", e);
        }
    }


    private void setDefaultLauncher(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, HomeActivity.class);
        Intent selectorIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        selectorIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        selectorIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        selectorIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        selectorIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Disable the default launcher (Android portal)
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName("com.google.android.tvlauncher", "com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        // Enable your app as the default launcher
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        // Start the selector intent to make your app the default launcher
        context.startActivity(selectorIntent);
    }
}



Here is my manifest :


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ansetech.hospitv">

    <permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ReservedSystemPermission" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HOME" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ReservedSystemPermission" />
    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <!-- Add other permissions here -->

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_ansetech"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_ansetech"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ShoppingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/uptvTheme"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.InitCastActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/uptvTheme"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.BillingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/uptvTheme"></activity>

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" /> <!-- Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/HospitalityTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="com.philips.professionaldisplaysolutions.jedi.intent.category.PRO_TV_DASHBOARD" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_ansetech"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_ansetech"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_ansetech"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/uptvTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ConfigActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/uptvTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PictureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="com.philips.professionaldisplaysolutions.jedi.intent.category.PRO_TV_CONFIGURE_ACTVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DiapoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.WebActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
                android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.AppUninstallActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MediaDetailsActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.LeanbackModelDetail" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PIPActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.LeanbackPreferences" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.LeanbackPreferences" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MailBoxActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.LeanbackPreferences" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MailDetailActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.LeanbackPreferences" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ZfitnessActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.LeanbackPreferences" /> <!-- Receiver -->
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.MessageReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> <!-- Services -->
        <service
            android:name=".service.DownloadService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <service
            android:name=".service.NotificationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <service android:name=".service.OverlayService" />

        <service
            android:name="com.ansetech.hospitv.service.YourAccessibilityService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>


        </service>


    </application>

</manifest>




Can you share some of the code that you have so far? There's not much to go on in your question. Specifically, sharing the AndroidManifest.xml and your starting activity would be a good place to start.

Sure ! thank you ! i've edited my post. the part where i disable the default launcher ( android tv ) does not work neither...

You'll need to override the default launcher with your app on the system rather than trying to do it in code. If your app is registered as the launcher you will not need the BroadcastReceiver either.
